# When trying to overwrite a file, the original data gets deleted but not replaced

Tags: python

I'm a beginner and learning Python.

I've created this as to practice function writing. I understand it isn't necessary to write it like so.

My problem is that the out_file data gets deleted, and not replaced with the intended in_file data.

```
from sys import argv
script, in_file, out_file = argv

print "Copying from filename '%s' to filename '%s'" % (in_file, out_file)

print "The input data reads as: \n"

in_file = open(in_file)

print in_file.read()

print "The file to be overwritten originally reads as \n"

out_file = open(out_file, 'w+')
print out_file.read()


print "Now, to practice function writing, we will use one to   overwrite:"

def overwrite():

    out_file.write(in_file.read())

    print out_file.read()


print "The overwritten file now reads as:\n"
overwrite()
```

Thus the output of *>python ex20.py cat.txt dog.txt* is: (where dog.txt = "dogs are the best", and cats.txt = "cats are the best")

```
Copying from filename 'cat' to filename 'dog'
The input data reads as: 

cats are the best

The file to be overwritten originally reads as 


Now, to practice function writing, we will use one to overwrite:
The overwritten file now reads as:
```

Comment: When you `read` you're *already at the end of the file*. Try `seek(0)` first.

Comment: When changing to 

 print out_file.seek(0)

in def

the output is simply 'None'. :(

Comment: `out_file.seek(0)` then `print out_file.read()`. `out_file.seek(0)` has no return value.

Comment: @user5169396 `seek` just moves the file pointer - you need to move it **then** read, the move itself doesn't return anything

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think you can rather post it as an answer with more explanation

Comment: @VigneshKalai there are plenty of *"why can't I read from the end of the file"* questions already, I'm not writing up another one!